# Multiple models in HTTPPost action returns null

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a model called "Request" which has three more model within it as below

```
public partial class Request
{
    public long RequestID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string RequesterName { get; set; }
    public string RequesterPhone { get; set; }       

    public virtual AccessLevels AccessLevels { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }               
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Project Model

```
public partial class Project
{
    public long RequestID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }        

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

Department Model

```
public partial class Department
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }        
    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }        
    public long RequestID { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

AccessLevels Model

```
public partial class AccessLevels
{
    public string AccessId { get; set; }        
    public string AccessName { get; set; }        
    public long RequestID { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Actions

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Request request, [Bind(Exclude = "RequestID")]Department department, [Bind(Exclude = "RequestID")]Project project, [Bind(Exclude = "RequestID")]AccessLevels accesslevels)
    {}
```

View Code

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("New", htmlAttributes: new { @class ="control-label col-md-3"})
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
           @Html.Label(@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), htmlAttributes: new { @style = "padding-top:7px" })  
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequesterName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.Label(@System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "padding-top:7px" })                
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequesterPhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequesterPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequesterPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Department)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">           
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Project)
        </div>
    </div>        

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccessLevels)
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the HTTPPost happens on submit, the models Project and AccessLevels are always null. Only the model Request and Department are getting values. If i change the order of the model in HTTPPost method, then i get the values for the first two arguments and the other two are becoming null.

Please let me know where the issue is happening

Comment: Remove all the parameters from your post method except the first - it should be just `public ActionResult Create(Request request)` You `Request` class contains properties for `Project`, `Department` etc. so parameter `request` will be bound with those properties.

Comment: The issue was that i had multiple form tags in the editor templates and hence was causing the issue, i have made sure that there is only one form tag in the rendered html and the issue is fixed

Comment: You also need to remove all but the first parameter as per my first comment. If `Request request` is not properly bound with the `AccessLevels `,  `Department ` and `Department` properties then you also have other mistakes in your code.

Comment: Yes, i have removed all the other parameters as you mentiond and other Entities are properly bound. Thanks.

Comment: I have built a Edit View for the same models above, In HTTPGet for the view, i am able to see the value for RequestId as request.Department.RequestId, but when a Post happens the request.Department.RequestId becomes 0. Any Idea why this happens

Comment: Have you rendered a control for it?

Comment: No, RequestId does not have a control. Once i added a control for it, it started working. Thanks a lot for the help.